# Placing an arrowbox between two sections

Tags: html, css, between

I don't really know how to approach this, but this is what I'm trying to do, placing the white arrowbox:

[image]

I know how to do an arrowbox, but placing it like that is a mystery to me. At the moment I have two sections, upper and lower, and then tried giving the box an absolute position, but didn't work.

How should I approach this problem? I'm sure there is an easy solution, but I'm not that experienced with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didn't understand your question very well myself. IF you are trying to position your box in the middle of the lower blue container with: position:absolute I would try this myself

```
.box {
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:red;    
    position:absolute;
    top:-50px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px; /*this has to be half your box width negative margin*/
}
```

Don't forget to add position relative to your blue div (or fixed, or absolute... just not default static). A fiddle as an example ( I add css box arrow just in case you need it): http://jsfiddle.net/j5a0227s/1/

Comment: More compact than mine! Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly misunderstood your question. Please see the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qz4twty4/1/).

This places a green block below the middle circle, but by giving it the `position: absolute`, you can change the location with `margin-top`. I don't know how this reacts in responsive websites, you might want to tweak it a bit.

**Edit2: Even better is to place the white block in the div you have above the circles. See this updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qz4twty4/2/).**

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container0">
        <div class="hover2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
    margin-top:100px;
}
.hover2 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background: green;
    margin-left:180px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:60px;
}

.container0 {
    background: purple;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your two sections with a div and take a close look at this interesting article: [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).